Can I force https on the browser when javascript library sets img-src?
Using CanadaPost AddressComplete library that has the following snipet:
    /* Preload images that are to be used in the css. */
    function preloadImage(url) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
    }

    preloadImage('//' + pca.host + '/images/icons/captureplus/loqatelogoinverted.svg');
    preloadImage('//' + pca.host + '/images/icons/captureplus/geolocationicon.svg');
    preloadImage('//' + pca.host + '/images/icons/captureplus/loader.gif');
    preloadImage('//' + pca.host + '/images/icons/captureplus/chevron.png');

Although I get the script via https, both Firefox 128 and Chrome 126 is trying to get them via http, violating our site's CSP.
Can I change the browser's behavior via javascript in my own JS code or in the script tag that fetches the library?  I do not have edit rights on the JS library that contains the above snipet.    Or must I add http to CSP for img-src?

usually // should resolve to same protocol that page is using, and it definitely fork in FireFox. Do you serve your page over HTTPS or HTTP?

Adding "upgrade-insecure-requests;" to your CSP will turn all http resource requests into https.
